# How to use NearCache when using Apache ignite from JDBC Thin Driver?

Tags: ignite

I'd like to use Apache Ignite's Near Cache, can I set it from the JDBC Thin driver?

Looking at the parameters here, there seems to be no operation in Near-Cache ...
https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver#section-parameters

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, Near Cache is only for cache put-get operations.

SQL will always be executed on primary server node(s).